# Define format for Date.parse in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I am using Date.parse to convert a string to a date in javascript, however, if the string looks like this '10/11/2016' it is interpreted as Oct 11 2016, i need it to be interpreted as Nov 10 2016

Suggestions?

Comment: You can't change the format that the function accepts, so you have to just format it differently. Or split on `/` and make a date object by passing in the separate values `new Date(year, month-1, day)`.

Comment: According to the documentation, the format must be: "A string representing an [RFC2822](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#section-3.3) or ISO 8601 date (other formats may be used, but results may be unexpected)."

Comment: @Amy—that might be what [*MDN says*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse), but the language specification does not mention RFC2822 at all. MDN also says "*It is not recommended to use Date.parse…*".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default `Date.parse` consider in this format that **month** precede the **day** to be in your case **MM/DD/YYYY** not as you want **DD/MM/YYYY**.

I prefer/suggest using 3rd party date parser library as [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/)

It can take your **date-string** and the **format** to be like this:

```
moment("10/11/2016", "DD-MM-YYYY");
```

Comment: Your "by default" statement is not consistent with EMCA-262. Except for ISO 8601 extended format, parsing of date strings with Date.parse and the Date constructor is implementation dependent.