# How to convert a german date string into a date correctly?

Tags: javascript, date

I have a string, which I want to convert to a Date;

```
let dateStr = "01.04.1990"
let date = new Date(dateStr);
```

but if I try to console log the date I get `Thu Jan 04 1990 00:00:00`. As you see day and month are switched but why?
How would I convert that string correctly?

Comment: Use a library that supports format strings, split the string into its date parts and built the `Date` object with those parts, ... -> What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? You haven't found anything here on SO on how to parse strings?

Comment: I will try. Maybe its time to use momentjs

Comment: @Andreas I have seen interesting posts but to be sure that I do everything up to date, I asked this question here because I do not know whether things changed or things become obsolete

Comment: Try `new Date('01.04.1990'.split('.').reverse())`

Comment: @User863 Hey, that is also a nice short solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could reorder the values for an ISO date string and get the instance with this value.

```js
let dateStr = "01.04.1990"
let date = new Date(dateStr.replace(/(.*)\.(.*)\.(.*)/, '$3-$2-$1'));

console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

In genereal `Date.parse()` is expecting an [ISO-8601](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#ECMAScript_5_ISO-8601_format_support) formatted date string.

A recommendable approach would be to use a library like [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/), as suggested here: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40517851/define-format-for-date-parse-in-javascript)

Comment: @Opat Except don't use moment.js. It is "done", officially. Read their homepage for why and for recommendations what to use instead.

Comment: @Opat RoToRa - You indeed are right - I changed the answer to Luxon since it seems to also do the job of parsing custom formats.